# Typescript Event to pass data from one class to another

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I know it's a pretty basic question, but still haven't found answers in half an hour of research.

I have two classes. One holds my Google Maps API. And when a marker is clicked I want to emit event on the other class and pass it the data.
I have written some pseudo code, so you can imagine of what I want to do.

```
export class Class1 {
    someFunctionInClass1() {
        //some code
        this.functionHere()
    }

    functionHere() {
        gotanEvent() {
            google.maps.event {
                //here i got an event
                and want to pass data to Class2
                functionToCallWhenEventEmits(with the data)
            }
        }
    }
}


import { Class1 } from ../class1Path;

export class Class2 {
    constructor(public class1: Class1) {

    }


    someFunctionInClass2() {
        class1.someFunctionInClass1();
    }

    functionToCallWhenEventEmits(data to pass) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Hope, someone can help me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want event-like behavior between two classes, you can use a lightweight version of the Observer design pattern. Instead of maintaining a "list of its dependents", your subject will instead maintain only one dependent.

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern))

Here is an example of a lightweight observer pattern ([with a Fiddle](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Subject%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20observer%20%3A%20%20Observer%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Attach(observer%3A%20Observer)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.observer%20%20%3D%20observer%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20DoSomething(message%3A%20string)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.observer%20!%3D%20null)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20observer.Updating(message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Observer%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Updating(message%3A%20string)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.writeln(message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20subject%20%3D%20new%20Subject()%3B%0D%0Avar%20observer%20%3D%20new%20Observer()%3B%0D%0Asubject.Attach(observer)%3B%0D%0Asubject.DoSomething(%22Something%20happened!%22)%3B%0D%0A)).

```
class Subject
{ 
    private observer :  Observer;

    public Attach(observer: Observer)
    { 
        this.observer  = observer;
    }

    public DoSomething(message: string)
    { 
        if (this.observer != null)
        { 
            observer.Updating(message);
        }
    }
}

class Observer
{ 
    public Updating(message: string)
    { 
        document.writeln(message);
    }
}

var subject = new Subject();
var observer = new Observer();
subject.Attach(observer);
subject.DoSomething("Something happened!");
```

Comment: thanks that worked fore me :). I also had an error because Ionic didn't want to update the view. I have fixed it now. Thanks for your help